# How to define an interface attribute as dictionary in Typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, list, dictionary

I come from Python and on Python there lists `[]` and dictionaries `{}`.

For example, I can define an `Interface` with a `diagnostics` attribute, as a list like this:

```js
interface AppState {
  diagnostics: string[];
}
```

And it works correctly as a good list/array.

But, how to define an attribute of type `dictionary`?

If I try adding `{}` instead of `[]`:

```js
interface AppState {
  diagnostics: string{};
}
```

Typescript throws: `Parsing error: ';' expected`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the way.

```
interface AppState {
  diagnostics: { [key: string]: string }[];
}
```

Comment: must not include the `[]` at the end of line 2.

Answer (score 2):

Try to declare your interface like this:

```
interface AppState {
    [diagnostics: string] : string;
}
```

Then you use it like a normal javascript object:

```
let myVar: AppState = {};   

myVar["somestring"] = "value"; //set

let value = myVar["somestring"]; //get
```